# MYSQL to group tables and apply aggregate subtraction

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, addition, subtraction

**tablo1**
--------------------------------------
**firma**---------------------**alacak**
Firma1-------------------500
Firma1-------------------300
Firma1-------------------700
Firma2-------------------400
Firma2-------------------200

---

**tablo2**
--------------------------------------
**firma**---------------------**tahsilat**
Firma1-------------------300
Firma1-------------------200
Firma2-------------------100

*I have 2 tables. I want to group and aggregate the "firma" in table 1 and table 2. I want to get the results out.*

("tablo1" Firma1 -> 1500) - ("tablo2" Firma1 -> 500) = 1200
("tablo1" Firma2 -> 600) - ("tablo2" Firma2 -> 100) = 500
*The result I want to print:*
**firma**---------**alacak**
Firma1-------1200
Firma2-------500

*I tried a code like this:*

```
SELECT tablo1.firma,
       (COALESCE(tablo1.alacak) - COALESCE(tablo2.tahsilat)) AS sonuc
FROM (SELECT firma, SUM(alacak) AS alacak
      FROM tablo1
      GROUP BY firma
     ) AS tablo1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT firma, SUM(tahsilat) AS tahsilat
      FROM tablo2
      GROUP BY firma
     ) AS tablo2
     ON tablo1.firma = tablo2.tahsilat
ORDER BY tablo1.firma ASC
```

Comment: The result is "0"

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work with the right `join` condition:

```
ON tablo1.firma = tablo2.firma
```

However, in MySQL, I prefer using `union all` and `group by`:

```
select firma, sum(amount)
from ((select firma, alacak as amount
       from tablo1
      ) union all
      (select firma, - tahsilat
       from tablo2
      )
     ) tt
group by firma;
```

This works even if records are in only one table, regardless of the table they are in.

Comment: The result is "0"

Comment: I need your help in this regard.

Comment: @vduvencioglu . . . I don't see how this would return 0.

Comment: I can not get results when I write this way

SELECT firma, SUM(alacak)
FORM ((SELECT firma, alacak AS result
       FORM tablo1
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT firma, - tahsilat
       FORM tablo2
      )
     ) ON tablo1.firma = tablo2.firma
GROUP BY firma;

Comment: @vduvencioglu . . . There is no `ON` clause in my answer.

Comment: I could not run this code.

select firma, sum(amount)
from ((select firma, alacak as amount
       from tablo1
      ) union all
      (select firma, - tahsilat
       from tablo2
      )
     ) tt
group by firma;

Comment: @vduvencioglu . . . The code in my answer looks correct to me.  What error are you getting?

Comment: The row numbers in the table are not the same. Is it possible? The results is "0"
Firma1-> 0
Firma2-> 0

Comment: @vduvencioglu . . . This returns one row per `firma`.

Comment: Yes it returns "firma" but "alacak" remains "0".  Should be F1-> 1200 F2-> 500